# A tag for QFT in curved spacetime?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently asked a few questions about QFT in curved spacetime, and have noticed that there is no existing tag for this topic. I looked around the forum some more and found that there are several questions which would fall under this category, so I think it could be a useful addition.

However, when I tried to create a tag I was told that tags can not exceed 25 characters. This makes perfect sense, but then it becomes quite hard to create an appropriate tag. Therefore, I was wondering: What would be a good tag name for questions like these?

Comment: What did you try? [tag:QFT-in-curved-spacetime]?

Comment: I thought it'd be hard to find a tag that starts with QFT, so I tried to use something like quantum-fields-in-curved-space. But I guess, if there's no better alternative, this'll do.

Comment: How about "semiclassical-gravity"?  This would apply to all QFT in curved spacetime questions, and would also be valid for questions that involve backreaction and other effects that don't necessarily assume a fixed background.

Comment: That seems like a good alternative, although I recall reading somewhere that the subtle difference between QFT in curved spacetime and semiclassical gravity is whether one also considers the backreaction from the quantum field, something that isn't immediately relevant in my question. On the other hand, it's probably the most accurate thing one can get.

Comment: How do you figure it would be hard to find a tag with 'qft' in it? I would say it's the most natural thing people will search for.

Comment: Regardless of what tag this actually settles on, you should consider proposing tag synonyms using the runners-up to make the tag easier to find by new (and also old) users.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm not quite sure I know how to do that; could you tell me/point me to a place where I can read up on it?

Comment: The help center?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good use case for a combination of tags, like [quantum-field-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-field-theory) and [curvature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curvature).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe quantum field theory in curved spacetime is too specific.  Maybe we can broaden it up a little to something like "qft-in-classical-background" intending to capture all topics involving some sort of (non-trivial) background fields including gravitational ones...

I would envision questions concerning Hawking radiation, Unruh effect, Schwinger effect, fermion non-conservation by Monopoles, or Instantons *etc.* to all carry such a tag.

Comment: Good idea. Regrettably, your current proposal exceeds the 25 character limit as well... Any suggestions?